# Validate TextBox for Existing data in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am trying to validate some inputs for my database. User should not be able to save the same Title twice.

I am using this code:

```
private bool Exists()
{
    var entity = Factory.Definitions.CalculationParameters.List();    

    // List() lists all the values of the already existing data.

    if (AspValidators.ValidateTextBoxes(TitleTextBox)) //Validates the textbox for string
    {
        return entity.Where(item => item.Title == TitleTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Now at the `item => ...` part I'm getting this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'.

I don't know what to do. Help please?

Comment: Is it runtime error or compile time error

Comment: @RajeevKumar Compile-Time Error

Comment: are u sure item.Title is of string type ??

Comment: It should be, because the List() method, gets the data through the properties of the class. And the Title property is a string.

Comment: Hint: You are getting a list of items where the title matches that of the TextBox's Text. You should return whether or not this list is empty, i.e. if any such item exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is of return type of your code

```
private bool Exists()
```

You are returning 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable which is not of bool Type.

You can use this way

```
return entity.Any(item => item.Title == TitleTextBox.Text);
```